# python: generalizing delegating a method

Tags: python, magic-methods

I have a class like this containing one or more numeric elements.

```
class Foo:
    # ... other methods ...
    def _update(self, f):
        # ... returns a new Foo() object based on transforming
        #     one or more data members with a function f()
    def __add__(self, k):
        return self._update(lambda x: x.__add__(k))
    def __radd__(self, k):
        return self._update(lambda x: x.__radd__(k))
    def __sub__(self, k):
        return self._update(lambda x: x.__sub__(k))
    def __rsub__(self, k):
        return self._update(lambda x: x.__rsub__(k))
    def __mul__(self, k):
        return self._update(lambda x: x.__mul__(k))
    def __rmul__(self, k):
        return self._update(lambda x: x.__rmul__(k))
    def __div__(self, k):
        return self._update(lambda x: x.__div__(k))
    def __rdiv__(self, k):
        return self._update(lambda x: x.__rdiv__(k))
    # I want to add other numeric methods also
```

Is there any way to generalize this for all the [numeric methods](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#numeric-types), without having to do this for each and every one of them?

I just want to delegate for any method in the list of numeric methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the [`operator` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) here, together with a (short) list of binary numeric operator names, without the underscores for compactness:

```
import operator 

numeric_ops = 'add div floordiv mod mul pow sub truediv'.split()

def delegated_arithmetic(handler):
    def add_op_method(op, cls):
        op_func = getattr(operator, op)
        def delegated_op(self, k):
            getattr(self, handler)(lambda x: op_func(x, k))
        setattr(cls, '__{}__'.format(op), delegated_op)

    def add_reflected_op_method(op, cls):
        op_func = getattr(operator, op)
        def delegated_op(self, k):
            getattr(self, handler)(lambda x: op_func(k, x))
        setattr(cls, '__r{}__'.format(op), delegated_op)

    def decorator(cls):
        for op in numeric_ops:
            add_op_method(op, cls)
            add_reflected_op_method(op, cls) # reverted operation
            add_op_method('i' + op, cls)     # in-place operation
        return cls

    return decorator
```

Now just decorate your class:

```
@delegated_arithmetic('_update')
class Foo:
    # ... other methods ...
    def _update(self, f):
        # ... returns a new Foo() object based on transforming
        #     one or more data members with a function f()
```

The decorator takes the name you wanted to delegate the call to to make this a little more generic.

Demo:

```
>>> @delegated_arithmetic('_update')
... class Foo(object):
...     def _update(self, f):
...         print 'Update called with {}'.format(f)
...         print f(10)
... 
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo + 10
Update called with <function <lambda> at 0x107086410>
20
>>> foo - 10
Update called with <function <lambda> at 0x107086410>
0
>>> 10 + foo
Update called with <function <lambda> at 0x107086410>
20
>>> 10 - foo
Update called with <function <lambda> at 0x107086410>
0
```

Comment: Does this correctly handle the right associative methods?  e.g. `__radd__`?

Comment: Nice, I had a hunch decorators would help, I'm just not familiar enough with them to implement this. Thanks!

Comment: how does the "operator" module help here? why not just use getattr?

Comment: ...and I found one error: `__radd__` should delegate to `operator.__radd__`, not `operator.__add__`

Comment: try calling 11 - foo, you'll get the wrong answer with your existing code

Comment: @JasonS: No, it works correctly; there is *no* `operator.__radd__`, instead the handler reverses the operands.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- Is reversing the operands good enough though?  Doesn't that make some assumptions about the implementation of the various object's `__add__` and `__radd__`?

Comment: @mgilson: `__radd__` is being called *because* `k` doesn't handle `__add__`. The `operator` module will have to call `__radd__` on `x` instead unless `k` explicitly does handle `type(x)` objects. That's actually the right thing to do in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Use a class decorator:

```
def add_numerics(klass):
    for numeric_fn in ['add','radd','sub','rsub','mul','rmul','div','rdiv']:
        dunder_fn = '__{}__'.format(numeric_fn)
        setattr(klass, dunder_fn, lambda self, k: self._update(lambda x: getattr(x, dunder_fn)(k)))
    return klass

@add_numerics
class Foo:
    def _update(self, f):
        # ...
        return Foo()
```

Comment: there's an error here, your call to `getattr(x,numeric_fn)` should be `getattr(x,dunder_fn)`

Comment: yours is shorter than Martijn's; aside from specialization to `_update`, is there another significant difference?

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Martijn's is longer mainly because it handles any update function (it's not fixed to `self._update`) and it avoids `lambda`s (which might be a good style choice in this case).

Answer (score 0):

This might be *too* general, as it will dispatch any attribute not explicitly declared.

```
class Foo:
    def _update(self, f):
        ...

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        def __(self, k):
            return self._update( lambda x: x.__getattr__(attr)(k) )
        return __
```

You can make it a little more selective:

```
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if attr in ['__add__', '__radd__', ... ]:
            def __(self, k):
                return self._update( lambda x: x.__getattr__(attr)(k) )
            return __
        else:
            raise AttributeError("Unknown attribute: {0}".format(attr))
```

Comment: I thought about this at first, but where does `__getattr__` get `k`?

Comment: Good question :) I think I've fixed it, but I'm not sure I'm excited enough by this approach to fix it again if not.